# "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM" when i use implicit wait in two method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i use implicit wait on two methods it throws "StaleElementReferenceException" after executed first method and stops the execution after first method but when i use implicit wait for a method, both the method gets executed(but error print on console but not affected the execution).

Attached screen shot of error and code. I'm new to selenium and java please help me to sort it out.

```
public static WebElement prepProduct(WebDriver driver)
            throws InterruptedException {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);

            Boolean enable = driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath(".//*[@id='batch-update-prep-owner']")).isEnabled();
            if (enable.TRUE) {

                Select whoPrepsMerchant = new Select(driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath(".//*[@id='prep-items']/tr[2]/td[5]/select")));
                whoPrepsMerchant.selectByIndex(new Random()
                        .nextInt(whoPrepsMerchant.getOptions().size()));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By
                        .id("fba-inbound-manifest-workflow-view-manifest-prep-items-controller"))));
                String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.getFirstSelectedOption()
                    .getText();
            String whoPrepsvalue = (driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath(".//*[@id='prep-items']/tr[2]/td[7]/span")))
                    .getText();
            if (merchant.equalsIgnoreCase("Amazon")) {
                if (!whoPrepsvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("--")) {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']"))
                            .click();
                }
            } else {
                if (whoPrepsvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("--")) {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']"))
                            .click();
                }
            }
        } else {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']")).click();
        }
        return element;
    }

    public static void prepLabel(WebDriver driver) throws IOException{
        WebDriverWait waitLabel = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);
        try{
        Boolean enable = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='batch-update-label-owner']")).isEnabled();
        if (enable.TRUE) {
            Select whoLabels = new Select(driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath(".//*[@id='label-items']/tr[2]/td[5]/select")));
            whoLabels.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(whoLabels.getOptions()
                    .size()));
            waitLabel.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("fba-inbound-manifest-workflow-view-manifest-label-items-controller")));
            String merchant = whoLabels.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();

            String whoLabelsCost = (driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath(".//*[@id='label-items']/tr[2]/td[7]/span")))
                    .getText();
            if (merchant.equalsIgnoreCase("Amazon")) {
                if (!whoLabelsCost.equalsIgnoreCase("--")) {

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']"))
                            .click();
                }
            } else {
                if (whoLabelsCost.equalsIgnoreCase("--")) {

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']"))
                            .click();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']")).click();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue-plan']")).click();
        }
        }
```

Comment: it would help if you strip the code from branches that you don't hit.

Comment: Aside from the Problem you asked for, your understanding of the static field Boolean.TRUE seems to be wrong. Boolean.TRUE / Boolean.FALSE are public static final members of the Boolean class, not the actual value of your variable.

Comment: sorry i'm not understand your help. Please can you show me example in it or slightly change my code

Comment: yes i understand the static boolean.true / boolean.false now. how could i resolved the problem. please can you help me

Comment: then how could i pass the case inside IF Loop. i don't have idea please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are finding select drop down element. So change your code

```
String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

to

```
String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.selectByVisibleText("YourText");
```

or

```
String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.selectByIndex(indexValue);// 0 or something like that
```

or

```
String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.selectByValue("YourValue");
```

Comment: can you suggest where i have to make changes in my code to resolve it. I'm new to selenium getting confused alot in my code. Please

Comment: can u verify which line got an exception?

Comment: String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.getFirstSelectedOption().getText(); this is the line throwing exception.

Comment: I have referred the link you shared and changed the code accordingly by yet i'm getting same error @ String merchant = whoPrepsMerchant.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();. Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: No i'm finding the element in random manner that's why using . getText(). I want to get the text which is randomly selected.

Comment: select.getFirstSelectedOption( ).getText( ); -> This will retrieve the label text of the current selected list option. So choose your selected value specifically even if it is first item or not

Comment: how to choose the selected value without getting stale exception. can you help me to change my code accordingly.